# Stop sequelize create table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Every time I call a page, sequelize execute:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_p...

How can I disable this? the table is created and works fine, I no need sequelize try to create every time.

Comment: You are probably not going to get much help without posting the code in question.

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS` appendix mean table will not be recreated if it already exist. So, could you explain please why do you worry about that? Provide your code please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sequelize is doing this, because you either defined a many-to-many association between two models that don't have the option `syncOnAssociation` set to `false` or you call `sequelize.sync` somewhere.

Check this http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/usage#block-4-line-56

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/docs/usage/#options

But finally I kicked sequelize so I sent him to the moon. Sorry but I do the same with objects and crud querys, more efficient querys and, more development speed, and no strange facts.